# Select DateTime as Date while accessing database in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a grid view where in i am accessing the database directly in cs page.In database i have date format which displays as `2013-07-15 00:00:00.000` While using `select` command,and then i have wriiten to convert it into `Only Date` format as `select CONVERT(date, dojmu) as Date from Institutional_det` and its output is `2013-07-15`. Now i used the same query in asp.net but it displaying as `datetime` but not as `date`.

```
  if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Workshop")
        {
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.Name,m.FID as [Faculty ID],m.Type,CONVERT(date,m.Date) as Date,m.Theme,m.Duration,m.Organizer as [Role],m.UpdateDate from WorkshopSC_det m INNER JOIN Personal_det p  ON m.FID= p.FID where m.updateDate  between @Start and @End order by m.updateDate desc ", con);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;

            GridView1.DataBind();}
```

Gridview aspx code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Any Suggsetions are appreciated.

Comment: .Net doesn't have a `Date` as opposed to `DateTime`. You need to use a different formatting ("d") when displaying that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your SQL `select` statement as:

```
select p.Name,m.FID as [Faculty ID],m.Type,convert(varchar(10), m.Date, 120) as 
Date,m.Theme,m.Duration,m.Organizer as [Role],m.UpdateDate from WorkshopSC_det m 
INNER JOIN Personal_det p  ON m.FID= p.FID where m.updateDate  between @Start 
and @End order by m.updateDate desc "
```